# How to remove a future job with sucker_punch

Tags: ruby, sucker-punch, concurrent-ruby

I'm using [sucker punch future job](https://github.com/brandonhilkert/sucker_punch#executing-jobs-in-the-future) but sometimes I need to remove it in another request before it is executed.

For that I have to find it by the args I passed to the job before being able to kill it.

Comment: The library doesn't seem to implement the delete/destroy, however you could maneuver  through the queue (https://github.com/brandonhilkert/sucker_punch/blob/master/lib/sucker_punch/queue.rb#L19) and see if you could get the pending jobs if you could then then it'd probably have some way fo deleting the job as well.

Comment: Yes I tried it but it doesn't come with args, so I cannot select by it